# Store PHP settings data as array or MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, arrays, settings, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a Wordpress theme and it needs to have some settings. Until now I have them in the database but I also want them to be portable. For that reason I also saved the data as an array into a settings.php-file. Now I'm considering to don't use the database at all to avoid storing things twice.

**Some questions about this**

- Are there any bad thing about storing data in an array within a included PHP-file, compared to MySQL database? (It's just settings, nothing needs to be sorted, no relations needed)
- Which is fastest? Include a php-file with an array, or load data from the database?
- Other thougts about this?

I give a check-vote to the most complete answer to my questions. Short answers might get a vote up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a file based storage for your Wordpress-Theme-Settings if you want it to be portable. Some sites might have the themes folder readonly.

For the initial setup it's ok to read your settings from almost everything filebased. Later on its best stored (and backuped) in the database.

If you store things in a file use the [ini-style](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) based files as PHP gives you an API for free. Things usually only tend to be better stored in an array or [serialized](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) if your options are not restricted.

Don't care about performance too much, simply use the [wordpress options api](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) as a best practice.

Comment: That ini-thing was interesting and it looks good. Can you tell me why the ini-style is better than the array-style? Is it for the look?

Comment: No "hard" arguments, more personal ones: The ini file itself is more "focused" to some kind of configuration; commenting something feels more natural (for me, at least); better grouping of options. I'm sure I forgot something ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a pretty hardcore database guy and I would say they do not need to be in a database.

The clues are in your statements "It's just settings, nothing needs to be sorted, no relations needed"  and "I also want them to be portable"

My main argument is simplicity.  PHP is extremely good with arrays, it likes them, it understands them, can easily load them from files and save them to files.  So even if you do change them from time to time from the app, updating and saving an array is no big deal.  So, if you use the array, you use a native feature of PHP and that creates **architectural simplicity** for this feature.

So for portability, the most portable database is the one you do not use.  When you have the simplicity of using a native PHP data format, you don't need the database (at least not for this)

For speed, on Linux anyway PHP can open a file and read it faster than it can make a roundtrip to the database for anything.

The only remaining argument against an array solution would be interaction with other data, but you have said there is none.

So, as a hardcore database guy, I would say do not use the database just because it is there.  Databases are incredible for structured data, if this is just a flat list of settings it is not structured data.  The db can do, the filesystem can do it, pick what is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about portability, you might be interested in using ODBC or [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

As for which is fastest, I'm no expert, but the settings file only involves reading a text file and parsing it. The database option usually will result in TCP connections (unless you use mysqlite, which I would recommend if you are going to store more than just file paths and database names.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of having them in a file occurs if you want the settings to be configurable via the website itself.  If not, then having them in the code is no real cause for concern.

Comment: What if it should be configurable on the website? I save the file after I changed the settings.

Comment: @Jens: I don't see a problem with that. Just implement it, and move on!

Comment: Someone told me that if the theme folder is readonly there might be a problem to only use a file for saving settings.

Comment: @Jens Törnell: It is not an intensely easy matter to edit PHP dynamically.  And can be unsafe, as the file needs to be writable by the website.  If you are making dynamic changes to anything other than the database connection data, then I would recommend storing them in the database.